# How can we retreive the list of all service accounts in a GCP project which haven't been used in last one year

Tags: google-cloud-platform

### Script to retreive the Service Accounts "LastAuthenticatedTime" details

Used the script to get the Service account's "lastAuthenticatedTime" details. For few service accounts I see that value of "lastAuthenticatedTime" as null. Does that mean that the particular serviceaccount hasn't been authenticated at all.

```
PROJECT="PROJECT ID HERE"
LOCATION="global"
echo "projectId,email,lastAuthenticatedTime,description,lastRefreshTime" > unused_service_account.csv

# Obtain list of insight_id
INSIGHTS=$(gcloud recommender insights list \
    --insight-type=google.iam.serviceAccount.Insight \
    --project=$PROJECT \
    --location=$LOCATION --format=json | jq -r '.[].name')

# Iterate on each insight_id
for INSIGHT_FULL in $INSIGHTS
do
    # Cut insight_id
    INSIGHT=${INSIGHT_FULL##*/}

    # Obtain details of insight_id
    DETAILS=$(gcloud recommender insights describe $INSIGHT \
        --insight-type=google.iam.serviceAccount.Insight \
        --project=$PROJECT \
        --location=$LOCATION --format=json)
    EMAIL=$(echo $DETAILS | jq -r '.content.email')
    LAST_AUTH_TIME=$(echo $DETAILS | jq -r '.content.lastAuthenticatedTime')
    DESCRIPTION=$(echo $DETAILS | jq -r '.description')
    LAST_REFRESH_TIME=$(echo $DETAILS | jq -r '.lastRefreshTime')
done
```

Comment: Service accounts do not authenticate. The RSA private key is used to sign a JWT assertion. The JWT is valid without contacting Google. Most services have audit logs. Google does log details on the principal (service account email) in the log entry. Even that method is not foolproof.

Comment: Service account insight scans the service account activity over the past 90 days.